# Copying oldtable to newtable with slight differences in newtable?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables, oldtable and newtable,

oldtable looks like:

```
 id  | type | name 
 ----+------+------
  1  |    1 | dog
  2  |    2 | bird
  3  |    1 | cat
```

I want newtable to have its own id field and I want to insert all of oldtable's fields (including its id, renamed as parent_id inside of newtable, based on the constraint where type=1). In postgres I manually created the columns "id, parent_id, type, name" inside of newtable then did:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, parent_id, type, name)
SELECT nextval('newtable_id_seq'), id, type, name
FROM oldtable WHERE type=1;
```

which resulted in (as intended):

```
id  | parent_id | type | name
----+-----------+------+------
 1  |         1 |    1 | dog
 2  |         3 |    1 | cat
```

How do I do this in sqlalchemy assuming that my oldtable has more than a few columns and want to select all records pertaining to where clause? Also, is it necessary to manually create each column expected to be inserted inside of newtable before inserting oldtable's values like I did in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
oldTypeOnes = session.query(oldTable).filter(oldTable.type == 1).all()

for oldTypeOne in oldTypeOnes:
    session.add(newTable(parent_id=oldTypeOne.id, type=oldTypeOne.type, \
        name=oldTypeOne.name))

session.commit()
```